# How to Implement User-Specific Favourites using Firestore?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, user-controls

My project contains an array of MealPlans. Right now, a user can *star* a MealPlan and that will update the `isStarred` Bool value in the MealPlan document. However, this just updates the database that *every* user currently accesses.

How can I code it so that a user has their own personal set of *isStarred* MealPlans?

I'm currently using Firebase Authentication and Firestore. This is my MealPlan struct:

```
struct MealPlan {
    
    var docID:String?
    var title:String?
    var recipeSource:String?
    var estimatedTime:String?
    var coverImageView:String?
    var equipment:[String]?
    var instructions:[String]?
    var isStarred:Bool?
    
}
```

My User struct:

```
struct User {
    
    var userId:String?
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    var email:String?
    
}
```

My data model:

```
class MealPlanModel {
    
    var delegate:MealPlanProtocol?
    var listener:ListenerRegistration?
    
    func getMealPlans(_ starredOnly:Bool = false) {
        
        // Detach any listener
        listener?.remove()
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        var query:Query = db.collection("mealPlans")
        
        // If filtering for starred Meal Plans, update the query
        if starredOnly {
            query = query.whereField("isStarred", isEqualTo: true)
        }
        
        self.listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                
                var mealPlans = [MealPlan]()
                
                // Parse documents into mealPlans
                for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let m = MealPlan(
                        docID: doc["docID"] as? String,
                        title: doc["title"] as! String,
                        recipeSource: doc["recipeSource"] as? String,
                        estimatedTime: doc["estimatedTime"] as? String,
                        coverImageView: doc["coverImageView"] as? String,
                        ingredientsProduce: doc["ingredientsProduce"] as? [String],
                        ingredientsProtein: doc["ingredientsProtein"] as? [String],
                        ingredientsSpices: doc["ingredientsSpices"] as? [String],
                        ingredientsOther: doc["ingredientsOther"] as? [String],
                        equipment: doc["equipment"] as? [String], instructions: doc["instructions"] as? [String],
                        isStarred: doc["isStarred"] as? Bool)
                    
                    mealPlans.append(m)
                    
                }
                
                // Call the delegate and pass back the notes in the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: mealPlans)
                }
                
                
            }
            
        })
        
    }
    
    func updateStarredStatus(_ docId:String, _ isStarred:Bool) {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("mealPlans").document(docId).updateData(["isStarred":isStarred])
        
    }
    
}
```

And the method for starring in my View Controller:

```
@IBAction func starButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // Toggle the star filter status
        isStarFiltered.toggle()
        
        // Run the query
        if isStarFiltered {
            model.getMealPlans(true)
        }
        else {
            model.getMealPlans()
        }
        
        // Update the starButton
        setStarFilterButton()
        
    }
```

Would it involve copying the docID of a starred MealPlan into a key in the Users struct? And then displaying *those* MealPlans when filtering for *starred* MealPlans?

Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is for each user to track their own meal plans. You could create a collection that stores the meal plan id's within the users document so it would look like this

```
meals
   meal_0 //auto generated documentId
     //meal ingredients
   meal_1
     //meal ingredients
   meal_2
     //meal ingredients
```

and then

```
users
   user_0 //the documentId is the users uid
     //user info
     my_meals (collection)
        meal_0: true
        mean_2: true
```

That being said, it's often a good idea to keep data at a high level to reduce the amount of reads and simplify queries so this structure may be better instead of storing the users meals within the users document

```
starred_meals
   user_0 //the documentId is the users uid
     meal_0: true
     mean_2: true
```

When a use logs in, read their document from the starred_meals collection.

To expand on that a little bit, sometimes a user will want to store other information with their meal so instead the above, how about this

```
starred_meals
   user_0
     starred_meal_0 (auto generated documentId)
        meal_id: meal_0
        wine_pairing: "Cabernet Sauvignon"
     starred_meal_1
        meal_id: meal_2
        wine_pairing: "Barolo"
```

with that you could store all kinds of other information associated with each meal, per user

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation - I think it's making sense to me now. Does this sound correct?
1. Copy favourited mealPlan document to the user's document within the userFavourites collection
2. When filtering for favourited mealPlans, refer to that document to index/display the mealPlans from the master collection